# Why is it that the heat transfer is proportional to the temperature gradient?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

In a thermal conduction context and according to this formula : $\varphi=\frac{\Delta T}{R_{th}}$,
the heat transfer is proportional to the temperature gradient.

How does one physically explain the mecanism leading to that ? (At a microscopic pov maybe).

Comment: Think about a stick with two different temperatures at either end. What does temperature signify to you at a microscopic poy and think about what would be the situation of the atoms/molecules of the stick at either end. Also I think it is the rate of heat transfer and not heat transfer that is proportional to the temperature gradient....right ;)

Comment: None of the answers address the proportionality, only the direction of flow, although I think that was the question. Could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like water is flowing faster if a river is steeper most fluxes are proportional to some sort of gradient.

In your example it's a gradient in entropy, which can be thought of as a measure of order in a system. The system is trying to overcome the temperature difference in different regions which causes a heatflow, which is stronger the further the system is from equilibrium.

A nice example where you can see that a gradient in entropy does produce a measurable entropic force are polymers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_chain

Answer (score 1):

A rough outline: If particles move "double as violent" (which is called temperature), they bump double as much into neighbours thus passing double as much energy to that neighbour (which is called heat conduction).